# Javascript (no Jquery): How do I call a function on click?

Tags: javascript

After looking through all the JS docs out there, I just can't figure out why this isn't working: I've got a button with the ID of "next", and all I wanna do is trigger the function whenever the user clicks on that button.

```
    var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");

    var nextSlide = function (a,b){
        return a + b;
    }

    nextBtn.onclick = nextSlide(4,5);
```

So when the user clicks on the button, I can see the "9" in the console.

Comment: `onclick` expects a function, but `nextSlide` doesn't return a function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous function expression like this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="next">next button</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");

var nextSlide = function (a,b){
    console.log(a + b); // for display purpose only
    return a + b;
}

nextBtn.onclick = function(){
  nextSlide(4,5);
}
```

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/dhHBp)

Answer (score 0):

*Use*

```
window.onload=function(){
var nextSlide = function (){
                 this.add=function(a,b){
                        console.log(a+b);
                     return a+b;
                  };
                 };
var nextBtn= document.getElementById('btn');
 //nextBtn.attachEvent('onclick', new nextSlide().add(4,5)); //With versions less than IE9
 nextBtn.addEventListener('click',new nextSlide().add(4,5), false); //IE9 and above
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can say like this

```
var nextSlide = function (a, b){
  return function(){
     return a+b;
  }
}
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");
nextBtn.onclick = nextSlide(4,5);    // so basically the clicking on button will call the function being returned by function nextSlide.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
nextBtn.onclick = function() { nextSlide(4,5); }
```